# Camel Routing from AMQP to RESTful endpoint

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, amqp

I'm new to Camel and so far have been having fun with it.  However I've now come across a problem trying to read a message from AMQP and use parameters from the message to call a REST endpoint.

The idea is that the AMQP message contains a POJO which I'm reading to obtain the postcode and house number values.  These values are then being used to populate dynamic fields within the URL.
I'm using HTTP4 to perform the call to the REST endpoint and each time I hit that line I receive:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [spring-amqp://myExchange:getAddress:camel.getAddress?autodelete=false&durable=] [        46]
[route1            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [        13]
[route1            ] [setHeader1        ] [setHeader[CamelHttpUrl]                                                       ] [         0]
[route1            ] [setExchangePattern] [setExchangePattern[InOut]                                                     ] [         0]
[route1            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[postcode]                                                           ] [        18]
[route1            ] [setHeader3        ] [setHeader[houseNumber]                                                        ] [         1]
[route1            ] [log2              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route1            ] [recipientList1    ] [recipientList[simple{Simple: https4:{{addressmicroservice.address.url}}/${head] [        13]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: Address [houseNumber=null, postcode=DY10 4TW, line1=null, line2=null, line3=null, line4=null, locality=null, town=null, county=null] of type: uk.gov.insolvency.microservices.pojos.Address on: Message[ID-Andrews-MacBook-Pro-local-56293-1472721966485-0-3]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: uk.gov.insolvency.microservices.pojos.Address to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Address [houseNumber=null, postcode=DY10 4TW, line1=null, line2=null, line3=null, line4=null, locality=null, town=null, county=null]. Exchange[ID-Andrews-MacBook-Pro-local-56293-1472721966485-0-4]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: uk.gov.insolvency.microservices.pojos.Address to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Address [houseNumber=null, postcode=DY10 4TW, line1=null, line2=null, line3=null, line4=null, locality=null, town=null, county=null]]
at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:107)
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.createRequestEntity(HttpProducer.java:523)
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.createMethod(HttpProducer.java:422)
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:110)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:681)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:609)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:238)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:170)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:131)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
at amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$RabbitMQMessageListener.onMessage(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:201)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback.doWithRetry(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:162)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:201)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203)
at amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$SpringAMQPExecutorTask.run(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:316)
at amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$SpringAMQPExecutorTask.run(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:316)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: uk.gov.insolvency.microservices.pojos.Address to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Address [houseNumber=null, postcode=DY10 4TW, line1=null, line2=null, line3=null, line4=null, locality=null, town=null, county=null]
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:198)
at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:105)
... 49 common frames omitted
```

The Route that I'm attempting to create is:

```
from("spring-amqp:myExchange:getAddress:camel.getAddress?type=topic&durable=true&autodelete=false")
    .log("${body}")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URL,
              constant("https://api.getAddress.io"))
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    .setHeader("postcode",
              simple("${body.postcode}"))
    .setHeader("houseNumber",
              simple("${body.houseNumber}"))
    .log("${headers}")
    .recipientList(simple("https4:{{addressmicroservice.address.url}}/${header.postcode}/${header.houseNumber}?{{addressmicroservice.address.key}}={{addressmicroservice.address.password}}&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=true"))
    .process(processor)
    .log("${body}");
```

Using Camel 2.17.2 and Java 8.

Comment: [Liping's anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39268266/4657798) is correct, you need to marshal your body into an appropriate format. I only have an additional comment - instead of using `recipientList(simple("uri"))` you can use `toD("uri")`, much shorter and cleaner :)

Comment: @MilošMilivojević I had tried the toD prior, but read elsewhere that the recipientList(simple("uri")) was a better way for the dynamic urls.  Either way, I agree that toD is shorter and cleaner and have changed it back (although not in example)

Comment: Well, recipientList is certainly more powerful but I prefer the simpler way in most cases ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you error log, you need convert the message when exchange between the endpoints, you can refer to this [Type Converter](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html), or you can marshal/unmarshal the message to xml/json for alternative.

With camel, you can eaiser add the marshal json functionality just by call the marshal() like

```
from("activemq:My.Queue").
  marshal().json().
  to("mqseries:Another.Queue");
```

Comment: This helped give me the answer I was after.  I also added a TypeConverter to convert from Object to InputStream and added in the camel TypeConverter file to list it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with marshalling:

```
from("spring-amqp:myExchange:getAddress:camel.getAddress?type=topic&durable=true&autodelete=false")
    .log("${body}")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URL,
              constant("https://api.getAddress.io"))
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
    .setHeader("postcode",
              simple("${body.postcode}"))
    .setHeader("houseNumber",
              simple("${body.houseNumber}"))
    .log("${headers}")
    .marshal().json(Gson).convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .recipientList(simple("https4:{{addressmicroservice.address.url}}/${header.postcode}/${header.houseNumber}?{{addressmicroservice.address.key}}={{addressmicroservice.address.password}}&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=true"))
    .process(processor)
    .log("${body}");
```

Remember that you need camel-gson for that. For gradle use:

```
 compile('org.apache.camel:camel-gson:2.17.1')
```

And adjust with your camel version.